# What model changes cause AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException in product before migrations are run?

Tags: azure, ef-code-first

Consider the following deployment workflow, where staging and product use the same database:

1. Deploy application to Azure Website staging slot
2. Run EF code first migrations in staging (updating the shared database)
3. Test application in staging
4. Swap endpoints so that what was deployed to staging is now in the production slot

This process worked for a few releases, but today it didn't. The issue is around migrations ran in the Staging slot against the same database as the Production slot. We're every careful to not rename or remove any columns that would break production between steps 2 and 4. Today's migrations included a new foreign key and a script to create some tables for a forum control (there are no entities for these new tables, it's managed entirely by a third party control - we only added the migration so that we didn't have to manually run the install script).

We got the standard `AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException` below in the production slot after step 2.

> **System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException**:
>   Unable to update database to match the current model because there are
>   pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the
>   pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic
>   migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to
>   true to enable automatic migration.

**Is there a list of known changes that cause this exception? Or are migrations just not designed to be used this way?**

We've also considered something like [what SO does](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/05/03/stack-overflow-how-we-do-deployment-2016-edition/#database-migrations), but we'd rather not recreate the wheel if we don't have to.

Comment: Could it be that you have some changes in your model after you generated the last migration? That is what the message is saying, that a migration needs to be manually generated (if automatic migrations were enabled an automatic one would be generated). Try to do `Add-Migration` connecting to the real database and see if you get a message that says that the code is up to date, or either you get a migration with some content.

Comment: Also. you can run `Get-Migrations` to get the list of migrations applied to the database. You can also check the contents of the `__MigrationHistory` table.

Comment: @Diana I'm well aware of why the exception is being thrown, but I'm curious why some pending migrations trigger it while others don't.

Comment: Sorry I missed you point before. I guess the answer could be in your database initializer. Are you using `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` or a custom one? The former triggers when there are migration changes so it detects and tries to apply any pending migration, and as your db history contains a different latest migration that your production code there is the error. But it doesn't explain why sometimes you don't get the exception (you should get it every time there are different migrations in the new code). If you are using a custom database initializer the explanation might be there.

Comment: Useful info about initializers and this exception: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/magazine/dn818489.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Yes, we're using `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`.